Deserializing AuthenticationTicket using OWIN TicketSerializer error when using DataProtection API
I'm using cookie authentication in ASP.NET webforms app. I need to implement a session store for AuthenticationTicket object but when I deserialize the ticket, I get an error

Found invalid data while decoding

If I don't use TicketDataFormat in CookieAuthenticationOptions, it works. But I need this TicketDataFormat option implemented with the session store.
How can I deserialize the AuthenticationTicket properly in my RedisSessionStore class?
public class RedisSessionStore : IAuthenticationSessionStore
{

    ConnectionMultiplexer redis;
    IDatabase db;

    public RedisSessionStore()
    {
        redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
        db = redis.GetDatabase();
    }

    public Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        db.KeyDelete(key);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key)
    {
        byte[] ticketData = db.StringGet(key);

        if (ticketData == null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
        }

        var ticket = DeserializeTicket(ticketData);
        return Task.FromResult(ticket);
    }

    public Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var ticketData = SerializeTicket(ticket);

        db.StringSet(key, ticketData);

        return Task.FromResult(key);
    }

    private byte[] SerializeTicket(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var serializer = new TicketSerializer();

        var serializedTicket = serializer.Serialize(ticket);

        return serializedTicket;
    }

    private AuthenticationTicket DeserializeTicket(byte[] data)
    {
        var serializer = new TicketSerializer();

        var ticket = serializer.Deserialize(data);
        return ticket;
    }
}

StartUp.cs:
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            CookieName = authenticationAppName + ".AspNet.SharedCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login.aspx"),
            TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
                new DataProtectorShim(
                    DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Source\KeyRing\"),
                            (builder) =>
                                builder
                                    .SetApplicationName(authenticationAppName)
                                    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureBlobStorageKey), "/keystorage/keys.xml")
                        )
                        .CreateProtector(
                            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                            "Cookies",
                            "v2"))),

            CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager(), // default
            CookieDomain = authenticationAppDomain,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            SessionStore = new RedisSessionStore(),
        });
        
    }
}

